# Animate CAShapeLayer's bezier path with animation from center

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I'm trying to animate a chart so it scales from the center. Now it scales from left to right.

**Initial State:**

[image]

**Final State:**

[image: Final chart state]

**Animation:**

[image: Animation gif]

Here is my code:

```
maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
maskLayer.borderWidth=1;
maskLayer.fillColor=UIColorFromRGB(0x91E5FF).CGColor;
maskLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
maskLayer.path = finalPath.CGPath;
maskLayer.opacity=0.8;
[self.layer addSublayer:maskLayer];

CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
anim.duration = 4;
anim.timingFunction=[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
anim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
anim.fromValue = (id)[initialPath CGPath];
anim.toValue= (id)[finalPath CGPath];
[maskLayer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
```

Comment: If the start of you animation show the layer as it should be, and the animation moves to a state that you don't expect, most likely your `finalPath` is not computed correctly. If you scale something up, remember that the origin of you path creation code is in the top left, not in the center.

Comment: The final state is right, but i want it to scale from center point of chart. Is there any way to move the origin of path creation to center?

Comment: Yes, you can check out the `anchor` and `position` properties of CALayer. However it might be easier to create layer with the correct size and shape and animate it using the `transform` property. There is a convenience function to create a CGAffineTransform3D from an CGAffineTransform (this will help keep things clear and simple).

Comment: Thanks! Done it with CGAffineTransform3D.

Answer (score 0):

To get the results you want, you can't just scale - you'll have the same path at the start and finish. Your stated example has a path animation.

All you have to do is draw your paths in relation to each other, the way you want them to animate. If you want to animate your path as if it's anchored in the center, you need to draw them like that. Center both your paths on each other.

Here's a simple example:

```
UIBezierPath* initialPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: CGRectMake(-25, -25, 50, 50)];
UIBezierPath* finalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: CGRectMake(-40, -40, 80, 80)];
```

In this example, your square will scale up from the center. If your path is currently scaling from the right, it's because thats where your paths are aligned.